# Fatal Error Exception Class 'contact' not found laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a database named shop1 and there is table contact in it i use contact model to access the table contact when i want to see the rows in the table using contact model it works fine but when i want to edit it an error throws on to my face any help

here is my contact controller

```
<?php namespace  App\Http\Controllers;

use App\contact;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ContactController extends Controller 
{

//use contact;




    public function index()
{
// Show a listing of books.
$contacts = contact::all();

return View('index', compact('contacts'));

}
public function create()
{

return view('contactform');
}





public function handleCreate(Request $request)
{


 $contact = contact::create([
            'fname' => $request->input('first_name'),
            'lname' => $request->input('last_name'),
            'phone' => $request->input('phone_number'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'houseno' => $request->input('house'),
            'kebele' => $request->input('kebele'),
            'city' => $request->input('city'),
            'state' => $request->input('state'),
            'country' => $request->input('country'),
        ]);

}


public function edit(contact $contact)
{
// Show the edit book form.

return View('edit', compact('contact'));
}

public function handleEdit(Request $request)
{
// Handle edit form submission.
$contact = contact::findOrFail($request->input('id'));
$contact = contact::update([
            'fname' => $request->input('first_name'),
            'lname' => $request->input('last_name'),
            'phone' => $request->input('phone_number'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'houseno' => $request->input('house'),
            'kebele' => $request->input('kebele'),
            'city' => $request->input('city'),
            'state' => $request->input('state'),
            'country' => $request->input('country'),
        ]);


return Redirect::action('ContactController@index');

}

}
```

her is my edit view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

        <h1>Create employe <small>go on</small></h1>



 <form action="{{ action('ContactController@handleEdit') }}" method="post" role="form">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $contact->id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<label for="first_name" id="first_name" >first_name</label>
<input name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->fname }}"></br>
<label for="last_name" id="last_name">last_name</label>
<input name="last_name" type="text" id="last_name" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->lname }}"></br>
<label for="email" id="email">email</label>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->email }}"></br>
<label for="phone_number" id="phone_number">phone_number</label>
<input name="phone_number" type="phone_number" id="phone_number" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->phone }}"></br>
<label for="house" id="house">house</label>
<input name="house" type="text" id="house" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->houseno }}"></br>
<label for="kebele" id="kebele" >kebele</label>
<input name="kebele" type="text" id="kebele" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->kebele }}"></br>
<label for="city" id="city">city</label>
<input name="city" type="text" id="city" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->city }}"></br>
<label for="state" id="state">state</label>
<input name="state" type="text" id="state" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->state }}"></br>
<label for="country" id="country">country</label>
<input name="country" type="text" id="country" class="form-control" value="{{ $contact->country }}"></br>

 <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a href="{{ action('COntactController@index') }}" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
    </form>

    </form
```

>

her is my model

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class contact extends Model {

    //protected $table = 'contacts';
    protected $fillable = array('fname','lname','phone','email','houseno','city','kebele','state','country');

}
```

and here is my route

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\contact;
Route::get('/cre/{contact}', 'ContactController@edit');
Route::post('/cre', 'ContactController@handleEdit
```

');

the error is this

```
FatalErrorException in compiled.php line 7038:
Class 'contact' not found
```

Comment: is your model name contact.php or Contact.php ?

Comment: did you run "composer dump-autoload" after adding the new class?

Comment: contact.php and yes i run composer dump-autoload

Comment: Where did you save the contact.php file?

Comment: You do not need any use statements in your routes.php file. Is there a reason you have those at the top of your routes.php?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: Please try adding more details on how that command could provide a solution to the problem. That way, the OP (and anybody else) will be able to get a better understanding of your answer.